# sprite animation in XNA following the mouse

Tags: c#, animation, xna

my old issue was that my code originally would follow the mouse just fine, but when it reached the mouse it freaked out and eventually disappeared.

my current issue is that when I tried to fix the old one with an if statement, the sprite sits in its "still" frame and follows the mouse until again, reaches it and freaks out.

```
if ((distanceX < 1 && distanceY < 1)
    || (distanceX < 1 && distanceY > -1)
    || (distanceX > -1 && distanceY < 1)
    || (distanceX > -1 && distanceY > -1))
    walkCurrent = still;
else {
    if (velocity.X <= 0 && velocity.X > velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkForward;
    else if (velocity.X <= 0 && -velocity.X < velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkBack;
    else if (velocity.X <= 0 && -velocity.X > velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkLeft;
    else if (velocity.X >= 0 && -velocity.X > velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkForward;
    else if (velocity.X >= 0 && velocity.X < velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkBack;
    else if (velocity.X >= 0 && velocity.X > velocity.Y)
        walkCurrent = walkRight;
    if (elapsed >= delay) {
        if (frames >= 3) {
            frames = 0;
        }
        else {
            frames++;
        }
        elapsed = 0;
    }
}
```

this is the code pertinent to what I'm talking about.

```
distanceX = mouse.x - rectangle.center.x;
```

Answer (score 0):

answered my own question

```
if ((distanceX < 1 && distanceY < 1)
    || (distanceX < 1 && distanceY > -1)
    || (distanceX > -1 && distanceY < 1)
    || (distanceX > -1 && distanceY > -1))
    walkCurrent = still;
```

this didnt include a wall at 0, so it was ALWAYS true. now i just have to figure out how to get rid of the jitters and my program closing.sprite vanishing

Comment: What do you mean by jitters?